# Replace ' by ''

Tags: oracle, dbms-job

I want to use DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT inside a function from package, I use it like this :

```
if i_iscsv then
    dbms('true');
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(jobno,
                 'DECLARE            
                 BEGIN
                 get('||req||', '''||i_mail||'''); 
                 COMMIT;
                 END;
                 ');
```

The problem is from V_REQ, because I got a dbms like this :

```
DECLARE
                 BEGIN
                 get('
    select  distinct
         to_char( date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') date ......
```

instead of

```
DECLARE
             BEGIN
             get('
select  distinct
     to_char(date, ''DD/MM/YYYY'') date
```

My V_REQ look like this :

```
 V_REQ := '
    select  distinct
         to_char(date, ''DD/MM/YYYY'') date .....
```

How can I do to replace ' by '' ?

Thanks

Comment: `Oracle Scheduler` is more powerful and flexible than `DBMS_JOB`, which is a package used to schedule jobs. Although `DBMS_JOB` is still supported for backward compatibility, Oracle strongly recommends that you switch from `DBMS_JOB` to `Oracle Scheduler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Q'[]'` instead of `Single Quote`

```
 V_REQ := Q'[select  distinct to_char(v.date_min, ''DD/MM/YYYY'') date]'
```

[See the difference here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=653762680c4dafb2536e9b299e1c9b0d)

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution , problem is V_REQ in on multiple line , like  V_REQ := V_REQ ||'  ...  V_REQ := V_REQ ||' ...